# Filter store view based on Customer Group in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce website where we need to have 2 store views. One for the professional customer and another for the retail customer.

We need to have the same inventory but different product description, different attributes, and look and feel for wholesale/retail customer groups.

Comment: Same problem for me too. You could use this plugin: http://innoexts.com/promotion/customer-group/, but it costs 150 dollars. I am rather enraged now, because this is such a simple, but obviously needed feature, but still missing from Magento. It's a shame, that you need to spend hundreds of dollars on plugins, because the barebone Magento is just simply useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of Magento, with its catalog management and display tools, along with themes, is designed with this scenario in mind.  Generally you attach a store view with its associated catalog, pricing and inventory to a unique URL (e.g. wholesale.store.com and retail.store.com). Here are blog posts on how to do this in Magento [v1.3](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/) and [v1.4](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/setting-up-magento-with-multiple-websites-or-stores), however you could take a couple of different approaches.

One option for this is to write a custom module that binds an Observer to the `customer_login` event, and then sets a redirect to the Store that you have associated with their Customer Group.

There's nice [blog post](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/01/magento-events-explained-and-a-few-gotchas-avoided/) on how to use Observers in Magento, and a cheat sheet of known [Events](http://activecodeline.com/magento-event-hooks-cheat-sheet).  You can search Stack Overflow for pointers on starting the development of a custom module.  That should get headed in the right direction.