# Magento, How to add customer group field in new registration form?

Tags: magento

How to add customer group field while register a user in magento front end?

And is any way to differentiate web store based on usergroup?

Comment: You want a customer to be able to choose their own customer group?

Comment: Yes, i want to display the customer group option on user side....

Comment: Look at these resources: http://phpmagento.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/how-to-show-customer-group-selecter-in.html
and
http://developersindia.info/magento/magento-override-frontend-controller.html If you have problems, make sure you are [not leaving any spaces in between <tag>...</tag> in config.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201824/magento-select-customer-group-at-registration). As for changing stores based on customer groups, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742371/filter-store-view-based-on-customer-group-in-magento).