# How to register users as wholesale user in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have made a separate module to register the user as "wholesale" users. It opens separate page to enter the details. Now when users get register, the group of the user is "general" only.

I want to change that, When a user register from my module their group should be "wholesale". What should be done to achieve that?

Comment: you need to modify the customer registration page or create a new registration page for wholesale customer see http://midpart.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/a-new-registration-form-for-wholesale-customer/

Comment: I've done exactly this. I actually have followed this tutorial only. But thing is, users registered are under "general" group and not the "wholesale" group.

Comment: How to modify, I mean what to do now ?? Can you please guide me?

Comment: Actually you need to set $customer->setGroupId(2); for wholesale customer, checkout customer_entity and customer_group table and the data you are posting for customer registration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your registration form place a hidden field group_id and set its value to match wholesale group ID

In registration code add this.

$customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'));

you can get some trick from this link:
[Magento: Select Customer Group at Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201824/magento-select-customer-group-at-registration)

Comment: It worked for me ... though I am facing problem with normal login, but that can be figured out now. Thnx for the suggestion and links.