# adding a different customer example:seller through a different regestration page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9. I want to add a customer group as seller from the front end using a different registration form keeping the registration form for registration of general category separate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming - in fact you haven't even asked a question. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your registration the following field,

```
<?php 
        $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();
        foreach ($groups as $group){
            echo '<input type="radio" name="group_id" value="'.$group['value'].'" class="validate-radio" >'.$group['label'].'</input><br/>';
        }
?>
```

And save the fields as following in your controller file.

```
$customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost(‘group_id’));
```

Comment: <form action="http://127.0.0.1/magento/customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="form-validate">  -in the general registration the values are posted in that location which i am unable to find and i want the customer(seller) to be added in the same table where admin can view all customers

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201824/magento-select-customer-group-at-registration

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 600

Comment: @megha, check file permissions. Directories -> 755, Files -> 644. clear cache and then check

Comment: how to check the permissions i am using windows

Comment: i have tried --C:\wamp\www\magento>find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644    but it dint work